# difference between python print and sys.stdout() statements on linux

Tags: python, linux, stdout, stderr

I write some script in python, which interacts with user in shell. 
I used

```
print 'something'
```

to, actually, print something.

I run it through ssh on my remote machine and need to log errors, so I did

```
python script.py 2>error.log
```

but this command redirect my output to 'error.log' too. But when I changed output statement to

```
sys.stdout.write('something')
```

it worked. Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: That sounds rather unlikely, if only because `sys.stdout('something')` will not work; `sys.stdout` is not a callable.

Comment: `print` and `sys.stdout.write` both go to stdout, while `sys.stderr.write` goes to stderr (the 2> in this case). But as Martijn said, the supplied code is not valid Python as sys.stdout is not callable...

Comment: yeah, I've mistaken, sorry. It should be sys.stdout.write()

Comment: Are you sure your shell actually uses "2>" for error redirection. One possible thing is that you accidently got "2 >" which would make two an argument to the script (which will be ignored unless you look for it) and the > would of course redirect stdout instead of stderr.

Comment: @HannesOvrén I've tried many approaches, including variations between 2 > log, 2>log, 2>>log etc.

Comment: Just to be sure, the print output does show up in error.log? It is not that it was buffered and did *not* show up in the terminal and you just assume it ended up in error.log?

Comment: @Harald yes, it shows up in error.log. So it seems very odd to me

Comment: @infm: does `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__` before  the `print` statement help?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I've actually solved this problem, but I wanna know more about it.

Comment: @infm: `print repr(sys.stdout)`